# Magento recently viewed product not showing

Tags: magento, view, widget, product, wampserver

Hi in magento recently viewed product not showing. but it show on local (WAMP) server. but when i upload all files on Cpanel based hosting server it not showing up.

i use following code to showing it on view.phtml

```
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="reports/product_widget_viewed" page_size="20" template="reports/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml"}}');
echo $_widget;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using local.xml in your theme layout directory to insert the block rather than outputting using php. Here's an example from a site I'm working on. Ironically we are having problems with it displaying consistently, which I'm trying to figure out right now, but this is working.
app/design/frontend/your package/your theme/layout/local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view> 
    <reference name="content"> 
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" as="recently_viewed" />
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Then output on catalog/product/view.phtml like so:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('recently_viewed') ?>
```